# How validation works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m supporting API where I need to update validation into javascript method:

```
function AddCategory() {
    var category = $("#category");
    var subCategory = $("#subcategory");

    if (category.val().length > 0 && subCategory.val().length > 0) {
        var grid = $("#lstCategory").data("kendoGrid");
        var listGrid = $("#lstCategory").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();

        var dataS = grid.dataSource;

        if (!FindObjectInList(listGrid, "idSubcategory", subCategory.val())) {
            dataS.add({
                idCategory: category.val(),
                category: $("option:selected", category).text(),
                idSubcategory: subCategory.val(),
                subCategory: $("option:selected", subCategory).text()
            });

          dataS.sync();
        }
        else {
            InfoMessage("Category", "Selected subcategory cannot add again");
        }
    } else {
        WarningMessage("Warning", "Select category and subcategory...");
    }
}
```

I need to remove this validation:
     `InfoMessage("Category", "Selected subcategory cannot add again");`

But I don´t understand how this method works, anyone can explain me it? Regards

Comment: `InfoMessage` is not a standard method. Go read the implementation and see what it does.

Comment: `InfoMessage` is only custom notification message, but that I want to do is remove validation, so goal is that I can add any subcategories "n" times @MikeC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it works:

First, pass listGrid, idSubcategory and the value returned from subCategory.val() into FindObjectInList. If null is returned (the category does not exist) - then add the new category information passed in. Else, if the function returns true (the category already exists) then serve up the notification to the user via the InfoMessage function.

```
 if (!FindObjectInList(listGrid, "idSubcategory", subCategory.val())) {
        dataS.add({
            idCategory: category.val(),
            category: $("option:selected", category).text(),
            idSubcategory: subCategory.val(),
            subCategory: $("option:selected", subCategory).text()
        });

      dataS.sync();
    }
    else {
        InfoMessage("Category", "Selected subcategory cannot add again");
```